# Inserting a new line in a 2D matrix

Tags: python, newline, multidimensional-array

I have two functions that I can use to make an array:

```
    def makelist(size):
        list = []
        for i in range(size):
            list = list + [None]
        return list
    def mmatrix(rows,cols):
        matrix = makelist(rows)
        for i in range(rows):
            matrix[i] = makelist(cols)
        return matrix
```

When I make an array: `mmatrix(3,3))`, it prints all three arrays on the same line. How do I insert new lines between arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code to:

```
def mmatrix(rows, cols):
    return [[None for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
```

To answer your question, the clearest way is to print the lines one by one:

```
test = mmatrix(3,3)
for row in test:
    print row
```

Comment: I have to use the functions I specified, but I appreciate your reply. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it's just a formatting problem when printing. A solution is to join the lines with a linebreak:

`print '\n'.join(mmatrix(3, 3))`